# How to make a Symfony abstract type with different objects?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin, abstract-data-type

I made a custom model named [ExtendedDate](https://github.com/devaneando/CWCompanion/blob/master/src/Model/ExtendedDate.php) that behaves like a DateTime but allows all time periods, including Before Christ and *Anno Domini* years.

The model receives a string with the date (`-323-06-10` AKA `10 June 356BC`) and validates it. It's recorded in the database as a string  (`-323-06-10`).

The problem is, I want a friendly interface to use with Symfony and Sonata and want to create my own `AbstractType` what would be easy if I wanted to extend one of the existent ones, but I want my new type to have:

- an `integer` component for the year
- a listbox with months for the month
- a listbox with days for the day

And to convert those into a string timestamp which be converted into my ExtendeDdate model and validated.

I tried but. so far, I could not create such custom `AbstractType`. Maybe I am having the wrong approach here.

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: So what exactly have you tried?  Typically you would use a [DataTransformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) to convert the string to and from it's individual parts.  And then the form type just has the usual year/month/day stuff.

Comment: @cerad, thank you for yopu explanation. Nor exactly DataTransformer, but DataMapper was exactly what I was looking for and your leand took me there. Thank you a lot. Ps.: I fyou add that in your answer, I'll accept. Otherwise, I'll answer my own question and close this as answerred.

Comment: Glad you were ale to make progress.  Go ahead and post your answer.  I almost have the feeling you were talking about doctrine types and not form types.  Be interested to see where data mapper fits in.